# Finding Conditional sum to determine the Units Sold Units Remaining in inventory sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet [Here is the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aXU1rjEx3K57I5l16uIZ_kZLZM7Whem4gxKVBrBdIvA/edit?usp=sharing) which is used for determining the inventory at FIFO basis. I have different products that come into my stock and I sell them.

I bring in fruits and record entries in A to E columns using simple formulas. But the problem is here after the E columns from F to I. When the sale take place I increase the existing value in G1 and select E1, The formulas would dynamically display the selling price based on purchase price.

Say if I have sold 50 more apples then G1 becomes 550.

I am ok if the products are continuous like Green color (Apples), When the products are of different types they need to coined using SUMIFs or something else which I am not sure how to implement.

Please help to display based on yellow cells for entire table

Here is the

```
=MIN(C4,$G$1-SUM($F$3:F3))
```

[image]

Comment: Please make a copy by clicking link and in view only sheet click File>Make a copy option. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see if this helps:

`=IF(A4=$E$1,MIN(C4,$G$1-SUMIF($A$3:A3,$E$1,$F$3:F3)),0)`

The formula is for F4 and needed to be copyed down.

It uses sumif for a product name + checks if current product is "apple" or one you've selected.

Comment: You are the Man!, Really appreciate your help. Thanks a ton Max Makhrov